# What does the "sdl-config" mean when compiling sdl c program?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compilation, sdl

In many tutorials I saw `sdl-config` for compile a sdl c program. In c++ examples I have seen too.
Here is an example from [here](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/08_geometry_rendering/index.php).

```
g++ sdlExample.cpp `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -o sdlExample
```

What does the `sdl-config --cflags --libs` mean ? Why inside accent ?

Answer (score 5):

In a shell, where your command is executed, the reverse quotes imply command substitution. So, basically, whatever is within reverse quotes is executed as a command, and its output is substituted.

Example:

```
echo Today is `date`
```

Will first execute the `date` command, and substitute it's output.

```
echo Today is Sat Dec 19 14:32:13 EST 2015
```

Which is then executed to produce:

```
Today is Sat Dec 19 14:32:13 EST 2015
```

So, in your command,

```
g++ sdlExample.cpp `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -o sdlExample
```

The shell will first execute,

```
sdl-config --cflags --libs
```

And substitute its output,

```
g++ sdlExample.cpp <output of the above command> -o sdlExample
```

And then finally execute the resulting command line.

To see what is actually executed after command substitution, just add `echo` in the front.

```
echo g++ sdlExample.cpp `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -o sdlExample
```

This will show you the resulting command line.

Note that there is an alternative syntax for command substitution as well, which is preferred when you have complex, nested substitutions.

```
echo g++ sdlExample.cpp $(sdl-config --cflags --libs) -o sdlExample
```

This is a pretty standard technique to generate proper command line options for a library / framework, where the options depend on installation etc. In this case, the `sdl-config` command generates the necessary compiler options (`cflags` and `libs`) for the `sdl` package. You can experiment with what else it can do by executing it directly on the command line.

```
sdl-config --cflags --libs
```

[`sdl-config` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/sdl-config.1.html)

Answer (score 2):

It just outputs appropriate flags to pass on to the compiler, similar to what pkg-config does with its .pc files (located in /usr/lib/pkgconfig).